# Coded UI and MSAA hierarchy

Tags: c++, treeview, accessibility, coded-ui-tests

I'm opening a control using MSAA Server (Miscrosoft Active Accessibility) in order to automate tests over it using Coded UI. I'm using MSAA because the code is for VS2008 so UI Automation is unavailable.

It works good  except for the case when there are two control elements on the same Window. The problem is the UI Map Hierarchy generated. Its wrong, but for the case when you are dealing with one control, works ok.

The problem using the example with MSAA example, found on sdk:

[MSAA Server Sample from Microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuEpd.jpg)

So, when I map the window, I get the right map, but when I map a element inside the list, the element is right, but isn't mapped inside the list:

[Coded UI Map from mapping the events and asserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTfbc.jpg)

I have exactly the same problem in my app.

Thank you

Comment: Have you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Implementing_MSAA_server#Issues_with_Tree_Views? I don't know how much it would assist. I am not a software dev, but if you have the Windows SDK installed, you should have a program called Inspect32, which may help some.

Comment: Hi, I've read the Mozilla MSAA Accessibility and I've worked with the Inspect32. It shows the correct hierarchy but I cannot get the right hierarchy inside the coded UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that using a static `std::map<string,int>` to get an identifier when a new object is created.

So when a new object is created, I query the static structure with the current window title (I know this is a risky operation, but it works) and I get a new identifier.

I return the identifier when the MSAA method: [IAccessible::get_accValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318488(v=vs.85).aspx) is invoked

I add the Value search property of coded-ui to that property and it works as I expeceted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and answer to the Windows Message: WM_GETOBJECT, I've overrided the accessible methods from class CWnd.

The problem is the name returned by get CWnd::get_accName( VARIANT varID, BSTR *pszName) is the same in all chindrens of the window, so I've modified this method a bit in my class to add some extra information to identify my element.

And it works.